How prevalent are popular criticisms of academia?
I have seen this video by a very popular science communicator (Sabine Hossenfelder) shared around the academic community criticizing aspects of the academic industry and why they left:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKiBlGDfRU8
The main criticisms are:

Corruption in academia (in this case the head of the Institute made a significant amount of money by selling textbooks which his students would write for him)
The pressure institutions place on researchers to bring in grant money, resulting in a paper production machine that burns through students and postdocs and keeping them on temporary contracts and using overhead funds to pay staff
Constant moving and commuting required in academia, which negatively impacts mental health and personal life
The speaker shares their experience of pursuing academic research grants for financial reasons rather than a genuine passion for the project. They admit to lying to themselves and others about their true research interests, which never got done due to the need to focus on funded projects.

How universal are these experiences across academia globally and across fields? Is the academic industry moving away or deeper into these problems? Why do these issues exist in academia? How present/important are these problems in the day-to-day work/life of an academic? What would be the counter points for those who choose to stay in academia as to why it still may be an attractive career option for bright students?

On 2, why would students and postdocs not be on temporary contracts?

@JonCuster because they could be on a permanent contract, moving out of it because of:

progression;
being fired;
I understand that in the logic of "the winner takes it all" this is non-sense. But there are a lot of non-sense things that are the norm (for example: personal health insurance to cover cancer when risk factors are environmental and not personal) that it is not worthwhile to discuss it ...


Dear OP, all good questions. good luck in finding your answers, the community of Academia:SE is a winner community (compulsory reference https://xkcd.com/1827/ ) or even worse of people dreaming to be the "elected" one that will win the professorship in he distant future ;)
